# static lookup table in c for enum with assigned values

Tags: c, embedded

So my problem is basically the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374241/compile-time-lookup-table-for-enum) but in C so I don't have templates, etc. I have an enum type with assigned values so it is not continuous. Then I want to call a bunch of functions based on which enum is the case, all the functions have the same arguments. This is for an embedded system so speed and ram are both important. Ideally, I would define an array and point the values to function pointers, then in the handler function, I just call the function pointer at a specific array location.

The trouble is my enum has assigned values. For example when I have 20 functions with the largest assigned vlaue 0xA000, then this is a lot of empty bytes just sitting there.

Is there any other way to handle this gracefully without the trouble of maintaining a large switch case?

**UPDATE**

To make the problem a little more clear. The usage is on the slave side of I2C communication. I have multiple channels with different commands. For example, assume my enum is the following where the command is defined based on the first two bytes that arrive in I2C message.

```
typedef enum {
    COMMAND_1  = 0x0110,
    COMMAND_2 = 0x0120,
    COMMAND_x = 0x01A3,
    INFO_1 = 0x0210,
    INFO_2 = 0x0220,
    INFO_3 = 0x0230,
    SM_LAST,
} SM_t;
```

As suggested in the comment and mentioned in the question, if ram was not an issue I could simply do the following:

```
void (*sm_func[SM_LAST]) (arguments) = {0};

sm_func[COMMAND_1] = command_1_func;
sm_func[COMMAND_2] = command_2_func;
sm_func[COMMAND_x] = command_x_func;
sm_func[INFO_1] = info_1_func;
sm_func[INFO_2] = info_2_func;
sm_func[INFO_3] = info_3_func;

uint8_t handler(uin8_t request[2]) {
    uint16_t req = (uint16_t) req;
    (*sm_func[req])(arguments);
}
```

The trouble with this approach is that each member of `sm_func` has 4 bytes, now if when the enum values are `uint16_t` and are spaced out (for design purposes), then this can blow really fast.

Comment: Search the table once and save the function pointer.

Comment: @stark I know the function pointers, my case is similar to the linked question but instead of assigning a value, I'm calling a function.

Comment: I'm not seeing how what you said relates to what I said.  In any case, the linked question shows 2 possibilities: code (switch/case) or data (lookup table).  You already said you don't want code.

Comment: What are the enum values _exactly_? What do they represent? I/O port numbers? Where do they come from? Why aren't you putting them in a table and then passing around the index into the table thereafter?

Comment: Or just using the function pointer directly.

Comment: Just so we're on the same page, here's a simple vtable I did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777451/is-it-possible-to-do-inheritance-from-an-abstract-base-struct-or-simulate-someth/34781775#34781775 How would that be different from your issue?

Comment: You could generate a perfect hash function offline to map the enum values to smaller values. If the perfect hash function is implemented as a macro, you may be able to do it so that it produces a constant expression (when the parameter is a constant) that can be used as an index in the designated initializer for an array.

Comment: @stark Can you elaborate a little more? I'm not sure what you mean by using just function pointer. I'm fine with code, actually I prefer code if it means speed up and smaller memory footprint. Maybe post an answer with a little more detail.

Comment: @CraigEstey I updated the question with a little more information. Hopefully, it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `switch/case` is like a linear search through a table to find a table index.

What we want is something that takes the incoming two byte code value (e.g. "code") [which can be arbitrary] and convert this to a linear table index/pointer.

It *might* be possible to come up with an elaborate multitable lookup that (e.g.) takes the leftmost nibble as an index into the "zero level" table. Then, the next leftmost digit is an index into a second level table. This is similar to how virtual memory page tables are set up.

*However*, this can be complex and, although fast, it might use more memory.

With a virtual function table approach, we put the code into the vtable entry, along with any function pointers we need.

If the table is sorted, we can use a binary search to find the correct table entry. Below, I used a binary search to translate an incoming code into a table index/pointer.

The speed of this function (e.g. `vtblfind` below) is the crux of it. The binary search is *fast* and *general*. But, it may be possible to devise a specialized function that is faster

---

Here's some code that illustrates the binary search approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    COMMAND_1 = 0x0110,
    COMMAND_2 = 0x0120,
    COMMAND_x = 0x01A3,
    INFO_1 = 0x0210,
    INFO_2 = 0x0220,
    INFO_3 = 0x0230,
#if 0
    SM_LAST,
#endif
} SM_t;

typedef struct smctl smctl_t;
typedef void (*smfunc_p)(smctl_t *ctl,void *data);

struct smctl {
    SM_t sm_port;                       // I2C port value
    smfunc_p sm_func1;                  // a function
    smfunc_p sm_func2;                  // another function
    smfunc_p sm_func3;                  // yet another function
};

void command_1_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void command_2_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void command_x_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_1_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_2_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_3_func(smctl_t *,void *);

smctl_t vtable[] = {
    { .sm_port = COMMAND_1, .sm_func1 = command_1_func },
    { .sm_port = COMMAND_2, .sm_func1 = command_2_func },
    { .sm_port = COMMAND_x, .sm_func1 = command_x_func },
    { .sm_port = INFO_1, .sm_func1 = info_1_func },
    { .sm_port = INFO_2, .sm_func1 = info_2_func },
    { .sm_port = INFO_3, .sm_func1 = info_3_func },
};

#define ARRAY_COUNT(_arr) \
    (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))

smctl_t *
vtblfind(uint16_t port)
{
    int pval = port;
    int ilo = 0;
    int ihi = ARRAY_COUNT(vtable) - 1;
    int imid;
    int dif;
    smctl_t *vptr = NULL;
    smctl_t *vret = NULL;

    while (ilo <= ihi) {
        imid = (ilo + ihi) / 2;
        vptr = &vtable[imid];

        dif = pval - vptr->sm_port;

        if (dif == 0) {
            vret = vptr;
            break;
        }

        if (dif < 0)
            ihi = imid - 1;
        else
            ilo = imid + 1;
    }

    return vret;
}

uint8_t
handler(uint8_t request[2])
{
    uint16_t port = *(uint16_t *) request;
    smctl_t *vptr;
    uint8_t ret = 23;

    do {
        vptr = vtblfind(port);

        if (vptr == NULL) {
            printf("handler: unknown request code -- %2.2X\n",port);
            break;
        }

        vptr->sm_func1(vptr,request);
        vptr->sm_func2(vptr,request);
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I think the switch depends on the compiler implementation but mostly, they are not a linear search. A constant time is more usual

A smart compiler *might* be able to combine some tests into ranges or some other peephole optimizations, such as "conditional move" (e.g. `cmovne`).

But, it's still a "linear" search: If you have N cases, you need to do N compares, sets, jumps.

The compiler has to pick an order and the compiler *can* reorder them but usually doesn't because, to be true to the source order, it follows it. The reason is, that, if you have a case that is 90% most typical, you [the programmer] put that first, because you *want* that to be tested first.

If you recoded the `switch` as an `if/else` ladder, you'd be forcing the order. You'd want the same behavior for your `switch`.

*If* the cases were *contiguous* (e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, ..., N`) [or nearly so], the compiler *could* build a jump table and index into it. That *would* be constant [O(1)] time. For certain specialized `switch` sequences, I *have* seen a compiler do this.

Unfortunately, that is what we *don't* have here--the whole point of OP's question.

Here's a `switch` based function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum {
    COMMAND_1 = 0x0110,
    COMMAND_2 = 0x0120,
    COMMAND_x = 0x01A3,
    INFO_1 = 0x0210,
    INFO_2 = 0x0220,
    INFO_3 = 0x0230,
#if 0
    SM_LAST,
#endif
} SM_t;

typedef struct smctl smctl_t;
typedef void (*smfunc_p)(smctl_t *ctl,void *data);

struct smctl {
    SM_t sm_port;                       // I2C port value
    smfunc_p sm_func1;                  // a function
    smfunc_p sm_func2;                  // another function
    smfunc_p sm_func3;                  // yet another function
};

void command_1_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void command_2_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void command_x_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_1_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_2_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_3_func(smctl_t *,void *);

smfunc_p
funcfind(uint16_t port)
{
    smfunc_p func = NULL;

    switch (port) {
    case COMMAND_1:
        func = command_1_func;
        break;
    case COMMAND_2:
        func = command_2_func;
        break;
    case COMMAND_x:
        func = command_x_func;
        break;
    case INFO_1:
        func = info_1_func;
        break;
    case INFO_2:
        func = info_2_func;
        break;
    case INFO_3:
        func = info_3_func;
        break;
    default:
        func = NULL;
        break;
    }

    return func;
}

uint8_t
handler(uint8_t request[2])
{
    uint16_t port = *(uint16_t *) request;
    smfunc_p func;
    uint8_t ret = 23;

    do {
        func = funcfind(port);

        if (func == NULL) {
            printf("handler: unknown request code -- %2.2X\n",port);
            break;
        }

        func(NULL,request);
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}
```

Here's the [`x86_64`] disassembly [with `-O2`]. There are still *six* `cmp` instructions, which is the same as the six `case` statements:

```
0000000000000000 <funcfind>:
   0:   66 81 ff a3 01          cmp    $0x1a3,%di
   5:   74 31                   je     38 <L00>
   7:   76 37                   jbe    40 <L02>
   9:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   e:   66 81 ff 20 02          cmp    $0x220,%di
  13:   74 28                   je     3d <L01>
  15:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  1a:   66 81 ff 30 02          cmp    $0x230,%di
  1f:   74 1c                   je     3d <L01>
  21:   66 81 ff 10 02          cmp    $0x210,%di
  26:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  2b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  30:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne %rdx,%rax
  34:   c3                      retq
  35:   0f 1f 00                nopl   (%rax)
  38:L00 b8 00 00 00 00         mov    $0x0,%eax
  3d:L01 c3                     retq
  3e:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  40:L02 b8 00 00 00 00         mov    $0x0,%eax
  45:   66 81 ff 10 01          cmp    $0x110,%di
  4a:   74 f1                   je     3d <L01>
  4c:   66 81 ff 20 01          cmp    $0x120,%di
  51:   ba 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edx
  56:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  5b:   48 0f 45 c2             cmovne %rdx,%rax
  5f:   c3                      retq
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> I think this is the best performance that can be achieved using low-level languages (probably faster than higher performance solutions in high-level languages).

Yes, this is about the fastest, given the two byte "key" you have. It doesn't "hash" too well [any decent hash algorithm would be slower--see below].

> I was hoping to find something like a `python` dictionary where the key would be the `enum` and the value would be function pointer.

Ah, `python` ... [Personally, I prefer `perl`, but a topic for another time, perhaps ;-)].

What you're talking about with a `python` dictionary is what `perl` calls a "hash" [aka "associative array"].

Indexing into it, *deceptively* looks like an O(1) operation [based on the syntax], but, it's much more under the hood [which is the level we have to talk about when using `c`].

A two byte key doesn't benefit too much from a hash. So, let's consider an arbitrary length buffer (e.g. a string).

We compute a [32 bit] hash value. For fixed constant strings, the `perl/python` compiler could compute the hash value at compile time.

Either way, we use the hash value (modulo the number of hash buckets) to index into a hash table to get the address of a sub-list. We have to traverse that list to find a match on the actual key.

The sub-list is typically a singly [or doubly] linked list. So, we have to traverse that.

Or, the sub-list could be a sorted array and we could use a binary search. Or, it could be a balanced tree (e.g. a red/black tree). But, these are more problematic in the general case.

Here's a rewrite of my original code that finds the descriptor based on a string/length. For brevity, this only has the "search" code [and *not* insert/update/delete].

Note that the `strhash` function I'm using is a ripoff of perl's actual hash function. `python` will use something similar. The execution time for a given search will be on par with either `python` or `perl`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// strhash -- calculate a string hash
uint32_t
strhash(const void *bf,size_t bflen)
{
    const uint8_t *bp;
    const uint8_t *bfe;
    uint32_t hash;

    bp = bf;
    bfe = bp + bflen;

    hash = 0x37FB26C5;

    for (;  bp < bfe;  ++bp) {
        hash += *bp;
        hash += hash << 10;
        hash ^= hash >> 6;
    }

    hash += hash << 3;
    hash ^= hash >> 11;
    hash += hash << 15;

    return hash;
}

typedef struct smctl smctl_t;
typedef void (*smfunc_p)(smctl_t *ctl,void *data);

struct smctl {
    uint32_t sm_hash;                   // hash value
    const uint8_t *sm_key;              // key value
    size_t sm_keylen;                   // length of sm_key
    smctl_t *sm_next;                   // pointer to next element on sublist

    smfunc_p sm_func1;                  // a function
    smfunc_p sm_func2;                  // another function
    smfunc_p sm_func3;                  // yet another function
};

// hash table element
typedef struct {
    smctl_t *list_head;                 // head of list
} vlist_t;

// hash table
#define HASHMAX     256
vlist_t hashlist[HASHMAX];

smctl_t *
vtblfind(const void *buf,size_t buflen)
{
    uint32_t hash;
    smctl_t *ctl;

    // get hash value for buffer
    hash = strhash(buf,buflen);

    // locate hash bucket
    vlist_t *vlist = &hashlist[hash % HASHMAX];

    // scan hash bucket for match
    for (ctl = vlist->list_head;  ctl != NULL;  ctl = ctl->sm_next) {
        // hash values must match
        if (hash != ctl->sm_hash)
            continue;

        // key length must match
        if (ctl->sm_keylen != buflen)
            continue;

        // do compare of key/buffer contents
        if (memcmp(ctl->sm_key,buf,buflen) == 0)
            break;
    }

    return ctl;
}

void
test(void)
{

    smctl_t *ctl = vtblfind("the quick brown fox",19);
    printf("test: ctl=%p\n",ctl);
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

> I was hoping that someone has come up with a simple, static, heuristic hashing function for these cases that doesn't need collision resolution etc.

Either the `switch` or the binary search doesn't use collision resolution. That was just for the string example.

> I guess for the number of commands I have (around 50)

The rule of thumb is linear search for up to ~20 items and binary search for larger.

With the *exact* list of port numbers, it's possible to get a "smart" locator. That is, maybe a 2 level lookup based on MSB and then LSB. Or, something compact but fast based on tricks that are specific to the actual port numbers.

Because you've got a speed/space tradeoff, you'll have to measure/benchmark to find the optimal mix.

> a switch case would be the best way to go for code maintainability. I can put the most commonly used commands on top to save some speed

My general rule is: *If you can't measure it, you can't tune it*

As I [and others] have mentioned, a table would be just about as fast and with a smaller memory footprint than a `switch`. The table might even be faster due to the smaller loading on the processor instruction cache.

The `switch` doesn't *scale* too well. If you had a million types, the table would be obvious. If you had two, the `switch` would be obvious. Whenever I've had to make a `switch` vs. table decision, I've usually found the table approach to be the winner based on several factors. YMMV.

For the binary search, if you don't want to have to have the list sorted by hand, you could just use (e.g.) a `qsort` call during initialization.

If you decide to order the table by highest-to-lowest frequency, a linear search would be the best.

Another method would be a "cache" of the most frequently found/used entries (aka "memoization"). If there is a cache hit, use it. If not, the "slow" path (i.e. binary search) can be used. The cache replacement can be based on either LRU or frequency.

Consider a multistep design process. You could start with the binary search implementation. It's probably the best overall space/speed tradeoff.

Get it working. Use that to collect frequency data and benchmark values. See if there is a pattern (e.g. portA is always followed by portB). The data collected could help guide you to a more optimal solution for your use case.

Here's some code that illustrates the cache approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint32_t u32;

typedef enum {
    COMMAND_1 = 0x0110,
    COMMAND_2 = 0x0120,
    COMMAND_x = 0x01A3,
    INFO_1 = 0x0210,
    INFO_2 = 0x0220,
    INFO_3 = 0x0230,
#if 0
    SM_LAST,
#endif
} SM_t;

typedef struct smctl smctl_t;
typedef void (*smfunc_p)(smctl_t *ctl,void *data);

struct smctl {
    SM_t sm_port;                       // I2C port value
    u32 sm_freq;                        // frequency count

    smfunc_p sm_func1;                  // a function
    smfunc_p sm_func2;                  // another function
    smfunc_p sm_func3;                  // yet another function
};

void command_1_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void command_2_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void command_x_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_1_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_2_func(smctl_t *,void *);
void info_3_func(smctl_t *,void *);

smctl_t vtable[] = {
    { .sm_port = COMMAND_1, .sm_func1 = command_1_func },
    { .sm_port = COMMAND_2, .sm_func1 = command_2_func },
    { .sm_port = COMMAND_x, .sm_func1 = command_x_func },
    { .sm_port = INFO_1, .sm_func1 = info_1_func },
    { .sm_port = INFO_2, .sm_func1 = info_2_func },
    { .sm_port = INFO_3, .sm_func1 = info_3_func },
};

typedef struct {
#if OPT_CASHPORT
    SM_t cash_port;                     // I2C port value
#endif
    smctl_t *cash_ctl;                  // pointer to control
#if OPT_LRU
    u32 cash_lru;                       // temporal value
#endif
} smcash_t;

#define CASHMAX     4
smcash_t cashlist[CASHMAX];

#if OPT_LRU
u32 lrucur;                             // current LRU
#endif

#define ARRAY_COUNT(_arr) \
    (sizeof(_arr) / sizeof(_arr[0]))

smctl_t *
vtblfind(uint16_t port)
{
    int pval = port;
    int ilo = 0;
    int ihi = ARRAY_COUNT(vtable) - 1;
    int imid;
    int dif;
    smctl_t *vptr = NULL;
    smctl_t *vret = NULL;

    while (ilo <= ihi) {
        imid = (ilo + ihi) / 2;
        vptr = &vtable[imid];

        dif = pval - vptr->sm_port;

        if (dif == 0) {
            vret = vptr;
            break;
        }

        if (dif < 0)
            ihi = imid - 1;
        else
            ilo = imid + 1;
    }

    return vret;
}

static inline int
cashcmp(const smcash_t *cash,uint16_t port)
{
    int match;

#if OPT_CASHPORT
    match = (cash->cash_port == port);
#else
    match = (cash->cash_ctl->sm_port == port);
#endif

    return match;
}

uint8_t
handler(uint8_t request[2])
{
    uint16_t port = *(uint16_t *) request;
    smctl_t *vptr = NULL;
    smcash_t *cashcur = cashlist;
    smcash_t *cashold = cashlist;
    smcash_t *cashmatch = NULL;
    uint8_t ret = 23;

    do {
#if (! OPT_LRU)
        u32 oldfreq = cashold->cash_ctl->sm_freq;
#endif

        for (;  cashcur < &cashlist[CASHMAX];  ++cashcur) {
            // get exact match
            if (cashcmp(cashcur,port))
                cashmatch = cashcur;

            // find oldest cache entry
#if OPT_LRU
            if (cashcur->cash_lru < lrucur)
                cashold = cashcur;
#else
            u32 curfreq = cashcur->cash_ctl->sm_freq;
            if (curfreq < oldfreq) {
                oldfreq = curfreq;
                cashold = cashcur;
            }
#endif
        }

        // slow path lookup
        if (vptr == NULL)
            vptr = vtblfind(port);

        if (vptr == NULL) {
            printf("handler: unknown request code -- %2.2X\n",port);
            break;
        }

        // update the cache
        do {
            // no exact match found
            if (cashmatch == NULL) {
                cashmatch = cashold;
#if OPT_CASHPORT
                cashmatch->cash_port = port;
#endif
                cashmatch->cash_ctl = vptr;
                break;
            }

            smcash_t tmp = *cashold;
            *cashold = *cashmatch;
            *cashmatch = tmp;
        } while (0);
#if OPT_LRU
        cashmatch->cash_lru = ++lrucur;
#endif

        vptr->sm_freq += 1;

        vptr->sm_func1(vptr,request);
        vptr->sm_func2(vptr,request);
    } while (0);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think the switch depends on the compiler implementation but mostly, they are not a linear search. A constant time is more usual: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100473/Something-You-May-Not-Know-About-the-Switch-Statem

Comment: @anishtain4 The compiler generated code for a `switch` isn't "constant time"--it's still linear. I've updated my answer to explain why.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. I think this is the best performance that can be achieved using low-level languages (probably faster than higher performance solutions in high-level languages). I was hoping to find something like a python dictionary where the key would be the enum and the value would be function pointer.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Spoiler alert: you may never be able to view a simple python statement like `array["hello world"] = 1` the same way again :-)

Comment: I know how the hash tables work and python dictionaries are hash tables. I was hoping that someone has come up with a simple, static, heuristic hashing function for these cases that doesn't need collision resolution etc. I guess for the number of commands I have (around 50)  a switch case would be the best way to go for code maintainability. I can put the most commonly used commands on top to save some speed.

Answer (score 3):

Just do a standard lookup table.  The table size is likely to be smaller that then size of the code in the switch statement.

```
typedef void (*func) (arguments);
struct entry {
    SM_t  cmd;
    func fp;
} LUT[] = {
    { COMMAND_1, command_1_func },
    { COMMAND_2, command_2_func },
    // etc.
};

SM_t cmd_in = (SM_T) request;
func fp = unknown_request_func;
for (int f=0; f < sizeof(LUT) / sizeof(LUT[0]); f++) {
    if (cmd_in == LUT[f].cmd) {
        fp = LUT[f].fp;
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is the standard way I've done this every single time. You can also leave the last line with 0/0 as the command and pointer, and loop until you hit 0, which lets you easily add more functions without worrying about size changes.

Answer (score 1):

Translate non-consecutive values into consecutive ones with another layer of indirection.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

enum SM_e {
    COMMAND_1 = 0x0110,
    COMMAND_2 = 0x0120,
    COMMAND_x = 0x01A3,
};

enum SM_idx_e {
   SM_IDX_COMMAND_1,
   SM_IDX_COMMAND_2,
   SM_IDX_COMMAND_x,
   SM_IDX_COUNT,
};

// constant expression version
// one place for your "switch"
#define SM_TO_IDX(sm)  (size_t)( \
   (sm) == COMMAND_1 ? SM_IDX_COMMAND_1 : \
   (sm) == COMMAND_2 ? SM_IDX_COMMAND_2 : \
   (sm) == COMMAND_x ? SM_IDX_COMMAND_x : \
   (size_t)-1 )

// normal version
size_t sm_to_idx(enum SM_e sm) {
  size_t r = SM_TO_IDX(sm);
  assert(r != (size_t)-1)
  return r;
}

void func_handle_command_1(int);
void func_handle_command_2(int);
void func_handle_command_x(int);

static void (*const sm_func[])(int) = {
    [SM_TO_IDX(COMMAND_1)] = func_handle_command_1,
    [SM_TO_IDX(COMMAND_2)] = func_handle_command_2,
    [SM_TO_IDX(COMMAND_x)] = func_handle_command_x,
     // etc.
};

uint8_t handler(uin8_t request[2]) {
    uint16_t req = (uint16_t)req; // ???
    sm_func[sm_to_idx(req)](arguments);
}
```

Comment: This produces a huge conditional statement plus uses an array of function pointers. Are there reasons why the OP should not prefer a `switch` statement, which at least would have the advantage of saving the memory of the array?

Comment: I like the clever idea of using `define` to do the search in the pre-processing stage. But this has a lot of boiler-plate code and adding new commands would be error-prone.